# Does PostgreSQL have a "datetimeoffset" type like SQL Server does? Does an object like "2000-01-01 3:00:00 +4" exist regardless of system time?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, when I use `SELECT NOW()` or `SELECT NOW():TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'EST'`, any resulting TIMESTAMPTZ is displayed in my system time.

On the other hand, SQL Server has an explicit command DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS that can create a DATETIMEOFFSET entry with a chosen time and timezone, such as DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS(2000,1,1,3,2,4,9999999,4,30,7) would be "2000-01-01 3:02:04.9999999 +04:30".

It seems like Postgres' TIMESTAMPTZ aims more to be an unambiguous moment in history displayed in your computer's system time (ignoring the 1am-2am period that duplicates due to DST), rather than a stored datetime with a time zone specified.

Comment: No. [timestamp with timezone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT-TIME-STAMPS) converts values to UTC and saves them without the offset. This has the same problems as storing just UTC - if the timezone rules change you'll have to find and modify all those stored values. All it takes is for a country to decide to change the rules. Russia did so multiple times within a few years. Egypt did so with just a few weeks warning

Comment: The problems and the solution are explained by Jon Skeet in [Storing UTC is not a silver bullet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/). The solution is to store the *local* time along with the *IANA timezone name* and keep a calculated UTC value (or timestamp with timezone) for convenience. You can use `AT TIME ZONE` for this. Don't use non-standard ambiguous acronsyms like `EST` or `IST`. At least 3 countries use IST for example. Only the IANA names are standardized, eg `Europe/Berlin`

Comment: There is no duplicate in *...ignoring the 1am-2am period that duplicates due to DST*. If you look at the values you will see the timezone is different.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, what are you talking about, UTC does not change(leap second aside) with local time zone changes. As long as  the [timezone files](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datetime-config-files.html) are kept up to date you can reconstruct the correct local time from `timestamptz` at will.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Oh yes it does. Read Jon Skeet's article, unless you think the author of NodaTime doesn't know about timezones. And be happy airlines and travel agents don't store UTC and take care of the changes when they do, so you don't arrive one hour late for your flight. Russia changed DST rules 3 times in a couple of years, Egypt changed DST rules with just a few weeks notice. Imagine what would happen if we only stored UTC. How many millions of tickets would have to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct. PostgreSQL's `timestamp with time zone` is really an “absolute time” and does not store time zone information. If you want to store a specific time zone in a table, you have to use an additional column for that.

Comment: OK, is there a different datatype that stores a specific timestamp with time zone? Something like datetimeoffset in SQL Server?

Comment: @NovicePatience I already answered that in the comments. And Jon Skeet's article explains the best option to handle timezones. If you store local + IANA tz name, then adding a calculated `utc_time timestamptz` column for convenience should be just `utc_time timestamptz GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( local_time at time zone tz_name) stored`. While Moscow's offset may change from +3 to +4 next time they decide to change their rules, `Europe/Moscow` never will.

Comment: One case where you'd really need a `datetimeoffest` would be to record the exact value received from another system, eg an API call or an import, and don't really care about timezone conversions. While the `timestamptz` value is correct, it does lose the original offset

Comment: No, there is no such data type in PostgreSQL.